# Functional Test Keeps Failing (Rspec, Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I'm trying to implement an rspec functional test to check that a user is signed in with devise. I've looked through my code again and again and tried different solutions but so far nothing has worked.

I've included what I believe are the relevant files. Let me know if anything is missing. Any recommendations are appreciated.

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
# note: require 'devise' after require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
# instead of true.
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

# RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
# based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
# `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
#
# You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
# explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
#
#     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
#       # ...
#     end
#
# The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
# https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

# Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
# arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
# config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

#Added for Devise
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe UsersController, :type => :controller do

  before do
    @user = User.create!(email: 'example@example.com', password: 'example')
  end

  # let(:user) { User.create!(email: 'example@example.com', password: 'example') }

  describe 'GET #show' do

    context "when user is logged in" do
      before do
        sign_in @user
      end

      it "loads correct user details" do
        get :show, id: @user.id
        expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
        expect(assigns(:user)).to eq @user
      end

    end

    context "when no user is logged in" do
      it "redirects to login" do
        get :show, id: @user.id
        expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end

  end

end
```

And my feedback from the terminal after running bundle exec rpsec

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET #show when user is logged in loads correct user details
     Failure/Error: elsif user?

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user?' for #<Ability:0x007fa1d784cb98>
     # ./app/models/ability.rb:9:in `initialize'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cancancan-1.15.0/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:361:in `new'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cancancan-1.15.0/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:361:in `current_ability'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cancancan-1.15.0/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:342:in `authorize!'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cancancan-1.15.0/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:49:in `authorize_resource'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cancancan-1.15.0/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:34:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cancancan-1.15.0/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_action'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.1/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:33:in `block in process'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:100:in `catch'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:100:in `_catch_warden'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:33:in `process'
     # /Users/Admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.1/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET #show when no user is logged in redirects to login
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)

       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/users/sign_in>.
       Expected "http://test.host/" to be === "http://test.host/users/sign_in".
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:29:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.90214 seconds (files took 11.05 seconds to load)
6 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:18 # UsersController GET #show when user is logged in loads correct user details
rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:27 # UsersController GET #show when no user is logged in redirects to login
```

Comment: check this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)

Comment: Thanks! I actually had a friend who helped solve it.

Answer (score 0):

A friend actually helped me figure it out. Apparently there's some issue that involves the seperate gem cancancan. I had to go into the models/ability.rb file and change a line in it.

In the original code the line if `!user.admin?` was just `user?`

So if you run into this same issue, that's the fix!

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new #guest user (not logged in)
    # can :manage, User, id: user.id
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    elsif !user.admin?
      can :manage, User, id: user.id
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```